# Using oink on Heroku by creating Hodel 3000 compliant logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memory-leaks, heroku, paper-trail-gem, oink

I am having a memory leak and am trying to track it down, therefore im trying to use oink on Heroku servers. Since Heroku does not provide log archives, im exporting them to Amazon S3 through the Papertrail add-on.

I have been able to succesfully do so, however, in order to use oink, my log files must be in a special format called "Hodel 3000 compliant logger". I have managed to do so in development, however I do not know how to create such log files in production (*heroku). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Juan Lagrange

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359552/oink-logs-command-not-working-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

The [hodel_3000_compliant_logger](https://github.com/topfunky/hodel_3000_compliant_logger) gem should do the job here; it's designed just for that purpose.

1. Add `gem 'hodel_3000_compliant_logger'` to your `Gemfile`, then `bundle install`
2. Add `config.logger = Hodel3000CompliantLogger.new(config.paths['log'].first)` to your `application.rb` (if you want to replace your default logger with the Hodel3000 one).