# Oink not logging to STDOUT in Rails 4.1 app on Heroku

Tags: logging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, oink

Previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986144/using-oink-gem-with-heroku/14145299#14145299) seemed to get Oink to successfully log to standard out in Heroku with this setup (which mirrors the setup in this [article on arches.io](http://arches.io/2013/07/understand-memory-usage-on-heroku-rails-app-using-oink/)):

**Gemfile:**

```
...
gem 'oink', '~> 0.10.1'
...
```

**application.rb:**

```
...
config.middleware.use Oink::Middleware, :logger => Hodel3000CompliantLogger.new(STDOUT)
...
```

Judging by the time of the previous questions they were probably using Rails 3. We are using Rails 4.1.4 and currently can't get it to log to standard out in Heroku. If using Rails 4 the developers from Heroku suggests using the `rails_stdout_logging` gem which ensures that your logs will be sent to standard out. We are currently using this gem so I'm wondering whether it is stopping Oink from logging to standard out with the above setup?

Locally Oink is logging just fine.

P.S. I tried setting LOG_LEVEL to info without success

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Nope - added an issue to the repo a while back: https://github.com/noahd1/oink/issues/33